# How do I add a logo to the navbar with css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Whenever the screen size increases the row height changes and the logo exceeds the height of the navbar. I'm stuck here and can really use some help

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="logo-desktop">
    <img src="E:\work\JensonWebsite\images\jenson-logo-desktop.svg" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="gallery"></div>
<div class="brands"></div>
<div class="contact"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
height: 100%;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.navbar {
display: grid;
padding: 6px;
background-color: #0E1848;
grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: 100px;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I can keep the height of the row constant at 100px, but it doesnt seem to apply to the svg image used as the logo

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: I have added the html for that page. I'm new to coding so I don't know too much about stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image to change height according to the row then add css something like this:

```
    img {
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

But if you want fixed image then use fixed height and width like:

```
    img {
        width: 200px;
        height: 60px;
    }
```